# Unavailable Service Message

Tags: user-expectation, users, messagebox

I am looking for a good message to tell a user when a particular service isn't available based on their address. Other services might be available for that address - just not the specific service that the user wants. What would be a good way to tell the user that the service is not available and why it is not available but also explain to them that the other service is available. [image]

Comment: You've wrote "tell a user when particular service isn't available based on their address," then you wrote "tell the user that the service is not available and why it is not available," so can there be other reasons why a service isn't available?

Comment: Well its kind of hard to explain - but for example: If you came to the site and were looking to get the Digital TV - but once you typed in your address it shows that the Digital TV is not available for your address, however the Cable is.

Comment: So it is based on the address and there will be no other reason for it not being available.

Comment: Yes for the most part - there are a few other rare scenarios based on the city or state

Comment: Still location though.

Comment: Those help icons are *suuuuuuper tiny!!* I'd go with @DarrylGodden's suggestion--ditch the tooltips and just append "...in your area" to your existing status message.

Comment: thanks for the feedback - i will make those changes, hopefully they like them!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should put an ambiguous message up, when you can just clearly show what is and isn't available and explain why.

[image: Available Services]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - sorry I cant upvote because this is my second week on here :(

Comment: Only other issue is - my manager wants the user to know a "why" the service isn't available - which is hard to do because there are so many scenarios - which is hard to create a "general" message which covers all scenarios

Comment: Where's the data coming from? Your original image showed a user either hovering or clicking a question mark, what's different here? You'd configure this message in the same fashion.

Comment: The data is coming from a Bing API which uses an algorithm based on the users address which will show in the system as a red or green area

Red - service unavailable 
Green - service available 

So what happens is - a user is expecting to receive the service they are looking for then when they find out its unavailable - they call customer service confused/upset/angry

Looking for a solution to reduce calls to customer service

Comment: So it's location based...

Comment: yes - address only and the few situations where some buildings may have a contract or agreement to only receive the Cable and not the Digital TV

Comment: "Sorry <service> isn't available at your location"

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from Daryl... Would this work ? Some generic message

[image]